# How to do this polygonal spiral effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

would you have a technique to distort lines in order to create portraits or shapes like this artist?
[image]
[[image: https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/276315485/Portrait_closeup01.jpg?auto=format&fit=max&w=8001]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: for the octagon or geometric shape it is not a problem. on the other hand I cannot create the lines in distortion to reproduce the image

Answer (score 4):

It is quite complex half-toning. Photoshop hasn't such preset pattern. If you convert a photo at first to greyscale and then to bitmap with halftone screen shading you can see there's a limited selection of patterns available - for ex. straight lines or squares, but not twisted lines.

In addition the image in the artwork example is split to polygonal pieces and the different sections have half-toning line pattern directions which follow the edges of the polygon sectors.

I guess the half-toning is generated by a program; I cannot imagine that I could have patiency to split the image to pieces and apply so many different half-tonings which must all be built manually.

Just to show what I mean I built a little resembling half-toning for a photo only with vertical twisted lines and by having only 6 different greyshades.

I drew in Illustrator one piece of a vertical twisted line and made with it 6 different black density variations as fill patterns. (I used illustrator to avoid the need to keep numerous different layers.)

The fill patterns are these:

[image]

One of the patterns is selected. The magenta lines are actually 100% transparent. Every pattern have one to make the patterns have the same size.

I dragged the patterns to the swatches collection.

I traced as grayscale with 6 colors a photo, expanded the tracing, ungrouped and replaced the fill colors with fill patterns (used Select > Same > Fill Color). In the next image there's the traced photo and the same after replacing the colors with patterns:

[image]

The pattern fill version can be too dense to be shown properly as a small size screenshot. Here's a zoomed piece:

[image]

The photo is a politician here in a local news website.

You can see there's harmful splinters (=isolated stray pieces) because the color area borders do not respect pattern rectangle edges. I tried to approach that problem with Object Mosaic but dense enough mosaic crashed the uderpowered computer and the legacy Illustrator.

As said I guess the half-toning is generated with a computer program which is designed for the job. A computer program could vary the width of the twisted line along local darkness smoothly with no steps and without unwanted splinters.

BTW. The splinters can be deleted in Photoshop by making a selection with the magic wand. Selecting contiguous black leaves  splinters unselected. One can draw a black rectangle around the image to connect the pattern lines together. But the pattern width steps are not fixed, there's only 6 discrete greyshades.

The whole job is possible in Photoshop. There one could make a posterized version of a photo to divide it to few grayshades. By making color range selections one can cut pieces of different fill patterns to get the half-toning. To save work one could make his own patterns to this free fake engraving script:

https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-engraved-illustration-effect-action-for-photoshop

**ADD: There's another answer** which contains a link to a site which has collected info of drawing making software. One of them is an experimental online image converter https://mitxela.com/plotterfun/ which makes numerous different high quality half-tonings which are actually plotted curves. There's unfortunately not just exact the same as questioner's example, but the program anyway makes interesting things. The author gives also the source code!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I tried on my side and I came to the same conclusion, do you have any idea of a program that would make it possible to do this type of work?

Comment: I guess you must use a general computer programming system. To do it one must be real computer programmer. To get free information and support it can be wise to start with 100% freeware such as GIMP. I am not a programmer and I unfortunately have a very limited knowledge of systems which allow making effects at higher abstraction level than for ex. by writing Python code.  I have seen ads of Filter Forge in that category, but it is not freeware. I have used only its low cost non-programmable version.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is a collection of free open source drawing tools available at https://drawingbots.net/knowledge/tools/svg-generator. The first on in the list is https://mitxela.com/plotterfun/ which offers a similar mode called *Polygonal Spiral*. Not a 100% match, but quite close, and with sourcecode.

Test Image via [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/de-de/foto/arme-gekreuzt-fotoshooting-frohlich-gesichtsausdruck-2379004/).

[image: 1]

Comment: That's a fine finding! The linked online program does  numerous high quality line plot conversions.